# cursor.callproc returns empty results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got such a method:

```
from app.database import db

def get_channels_list(user_token):
    data = jwt.decode(user_token, app.config.get('JWT_SECRET'))
    connection = db.engine.raw_connection()
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.callproc("permission_list_user", [958539, 'web'])
        results = list(cursor.fetchall())
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
    finally:
        connection.close()
    print(len(results))
    return success(results)
```

And when I run it I get `len(results) == 0` but when I run the same procedure via mysql console like that:

```
CALL permission_list_user(958539, 'web');
```

I get results it should return.

Comment: do you call from the same MySQL account? It could happen if you don't have EXECUTE privilege

Comment: I guess so because when I run this: 
    
    `cursor.execute("select * from users limit 10;")` instead of callproc I get results

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out from code posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320265/cannot-return-results-from-stored-procedure-using-python-cursor

Answer (score 1):

I`m having the same problem, I didn't like the way, but I solved running a SELECT query after call the procedure:

```
query ='call loginAPI("{0}","{1}",@logged, @hashAPI)'.format(user,password)
 select = 'select @logged, @hashAPI'

  cursor.execute(query)
  cursor.execute(select)
  rv = cursor.fetchall()
```

Looking for prettier solution.

Comment: I reviewed how to access the results of calling stored procedures in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546157/5320906)