# MySQL stored procedure when no record returned

Tags: python, mysql

I am calling a MySQL stored procedure from Python and it works fine except when there isn't a record that matches the SELECT criteria. In that case the results crash the code. In this example there isn't a id #9

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('get_data', [9, ])
    for result in cursor.stored_results():
    aaa = result.fetchone()
    last_name = aaa[1]
    first_name = aaa[2]
```

How do I catch the error?

Comment: Put the code between a `try`-`accept` block?

Comment: What is returned if run the procedure in MySQL workbench?

Comment: Could you check the post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320265/cannot-return-results-from-stored-procedure-using-python-cursor

Comment: the code crashes at last_name = aaa[1]

with first_name = volunteer_db[2]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable