# sqlalchemy flask extension error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently working on an app that uses both the ORM of flask as well as I need to use raw SQL queries for some stored procedures. But the problem right now is that when I try to use the raw_connection() function I get the error of the title.

```
from data.models.db_models import db # here is where the models are
def get_sales_performance_use_case(companyCode: int):
connection = db.engine.raw_connection()
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute(
        "CALL ExistingBillingYears({em})".format(em=companyCode)
    )
    yearsResult = list(cursor.fetchall())

    for row in yearsResult:
        print(row[0]) # some processing with the data goes here after executing but can get there due to the error

    cursor.execute("CALL GetSalesPerformance({em})".format(em=companyCode))
    results = list(cursor.fetchall())
    items = []
    for row in results:
        dto = SalesPerformanceDTO(row[0], row[1], row[2])
        items.append(dto)
    return BaseResponseDTO(data=items, success=True)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Has anyone encountered this and knows how to fix?

If I execute my procedures in Mysql Workbench everything is working fine. So I have no idea what could be wrong with this.

I am using Mysql 8.0.29.
Flask-sqlalchemy 3.1.1

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64292723/5320906) answer your question?