# Check if stored procedure in .callproc python was executed successfully

Tags: python, mysql

I have this snippet in my python program. I wanted to know if the .callproc function fired the stored procedure that I created in mysql successfully. Maybe check on how many rows were affected or return true if it was successfully executed. How do I achieve that?

```
delete_customer_email = input("Enter Customer Email : ")
cursor.callproc('proc_delete_in_customer', (delete_customer_email,))
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Possibly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546157/5320906

Comment: @snakecharmerb can you post this as answer? Ill mark it as answer. I use the code provided in the link and also change my stored procedure so it will return a result if there was no user found in the stored procedure.

Comment: It's usual to close a a duplicate in these cases.