# How can "cursor.callproc" of MySQL be replaced in MariaDB?

Tags: python, stored-procedures, mariadb

I have found examples how to call stored procedures in MySQL from Python using `cursor.callproc`.

But `cursor.callproc` seems not to be defined in MariaDB. I am using version 10.3.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I retested some of the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546157/5320906) of mine on `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.10-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)` and `cursor.callproc` worked just fine.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Please specify more details: Which python module do you use to connect to MariaDB, which MariaDB version and especially what doesn't work as expected (including error messages).